# I'm getting two errors having to do with incorrect Xcode grammar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

```
(MemberPage *)initWithString: (NSString *) s  {
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {
        //DO STUFF;
        UserNAME.text = s;
    }

}    
return self;
```

I'm getting:
use of undeclared identifier initWithString
expected ; before : token

I've haven't been able to fix this after an hour so far,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `-` token before your method signature and the return statement is outside the method body. Should look like:

```
- (MemberPage *)initWithString: (NSString *) s  {
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {
        //DO STUFF;
        UserNAME.text = s;
    }

    return self;
}
```

You may also eventually have a problem on the `UserNAME.text = s` line but without seeing your header file its hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tweaks that will solve this.  See comments inline:

```
// Add '-' to show it is instance method
-(MemberPage *)initWithString: (NSString *) s  {
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {
         //DO STUFF;
         UserNAME.text = s;
    }

    // Include this inside of the brace
    return self;
}
```

As a note, by convention your instance variables should begin with a lower case letter and then use camel casing.  So, UserNAME.text should be userName.text.  The compiler expects this.